# Amazon Order Items Some Fields needed not existing

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

my reference doc is this: 
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders/2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrderItems.html

i have an Amazon Order Id
and i used MarketPlaceWebServiceOrders provided by the Amazon MWS developers
* ListOrderItems *

Ive updated the 
.config.inc.php configurations.
uncommented the required sections..
and placed an Amazon Order Id using:

```
$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrderItemsRequest();
$request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
$request->setAmazonOrderId($orderId);
```

ive also used ListOrders to get some important fields as well

```
$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrdersRequest();
$request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
$request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);
$request->setOrderStatus(array('Shipped'));
$currentDate = new DateTime();
$dv = new DateInterval('P5D');
date_sub($currentDate, $dv);

$dateAfter5days = $currentDate->format('Y-m-d');
$request->setCreatedAfter($dateAfter5days);
$request->setCreatedBefore(
        date_add($currentDate, new DateInterval('P3D'))->format('Y-m-d'));
```

and everything is good and smooth.
but i need some fields which are not present in the response to this request.

I am basing my database structure from Amazon Fulfilled Shipments fields
which goes - Amazon Seller Central Page - > Reports(top Nav Pannel) -> Fulfillment By Amazon -> Sales(Left Nav Pannel) -> Amazon Fullfiled Shipments
on this page i can generate a csv file of which have multiple fields.
some of these are:
amazon-order-id, purchase-date, etc

i used the MWS steps above to gather these data but there are fields that are not present, of which i need them since i created my database structure according to the Amazon Fulfilled Shipment Generated File and some of these fields plays an important rolse
Some These fields are:
shipment-id, shipment-item-id.

shipment-item-id is one of my unique keys.

where can i get these fields?

Comment: Some fields that are included in the Reports are not included in other areas of the API. Unless you are going to populate your DB with data from the report Im not sure why you would model it that way.

You could pull the FBA Amazon Fulfilled Shipments Report through the API and see if it provides the info needed.

Comment: yes, Reports API can suffice my need in the case of DB structure. actually that is what i am using now. there are some missing data though (blank fields) in Amazon Fulfilled Shipments(under/generated-by Reports API or even by manual proc) that is provided by the Orders API.

Comment: can post more info about which fields are missing... maybe copy and paste what you are receiving along with the blank fields.